Does the Lyons group have 2 111-dimensional representations or just 1?
From what I can tell about the 111-dimensional representation of the sporadic Lyons group (modulo 5), an involution negates a 56-dimensional subspace. Thus, the double cover of the alternating group $A_{11}$ acts on this 56-space, while $A_{11}$ itself acts on the remaining 55 dimensions.
According to this webpage, $2A_{11}$ has 2 56-dimensional representations modulo $5$, which I assume are exchanged by an outer (parity) automorphism. Thus, I would expect each 56-dimensional representation of $2A_{11}$ to yield a different 111-dimensional representation of $Ly$. However, according to Wilson's textbook The Finite Simple Groups, the 111-dimensional representation of $Ly$ is unique.
So, is the 111-dimensional representation of Ly truly unique, or are there 2 representations that are almost identical? If possible, I'd like to see the Brauer characters of the 55-dimensional representation of $A_{11}$, both 56-dimensional representations of its double cover, and the 111-dimensional representation of $Ly$.

The Brauer character tables of $A_{11}$ and $2.A_{11}$ are in the printed Atlas of Brauer Characters, or you can access them directly from GAP. I tried $\mathtt {CharacterTable("Ly")\ mod\ 5}$ in GAP but it failed.
